# when I turn the switch off/on all others switches turn too

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project and there's part of my project is an interface containing all the employees so when I turn off the switch of one of the employee it's mean that his account is suspended, but I faced a problem that when I turn the switch off/on all others switches turn too, I don't know how to solve this if you have any idea.

here is my code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'DPClasses/database_manager.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  return runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ViewAllOperators createState() => ViewAllOperators();
}

class OperatorInfo {
  String name;
  String photo;
  OperatorInfo({required this.name, required this.photo});
}

class ViewAllOperators extends State<Home> {
  static List Operators = [];
  bool alarmIsActive = false;

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   alarmIsActive = Global.shared.alarmIsActive;
  //   super.initState();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text(
          "View All Operators",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black, //change your color here
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FireStoreDataBase().getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text(
              "Something went wrong",
            );

          }else {
            Operators = (snapshot.data ?? []) as List;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: Operators.length,
              itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: const CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                               "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3135/3135715.png",
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(Operators[index]['name']),
                      onTap: (){
                      },
                        trailing: Switch(
                        value: alarmIsActive,
                        onChanged: (bool isEnabled) {
                          setState(() {
                            alarmIsActive = isEnabled;
                            Global.shared.alarmIsActive = isEnabled;
                            isEnabled = !isEnabled;
                          });
                        },
                         ),
                    );
                  },


            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }


}

class Global{
  static final shared =Global();
  bool alarmIsActive = false;
}
```

Comment: You are using the same boolean for all the switches and thus they are all reacting to one change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you are using a single Boolean for all the list's users, you have many options on how to solve this problem, this starter code based on your code might help you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      return runApp(MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Home(),
      ));
    }
    
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      ViewAllOperators createState() => ViewAllOperators();
    }
    
    class OperatorInfo {
      String name;
      String photo;
      OperatorInfo({required this.name, required this.photo});
    }
    
    class ViewAllOperators extends State<Home> {
      static List Operators = [];
      Map alarmIsActiveMap = Map();
    
      // @override
      // void initState() {
      //   alarmIsActive = Global.shared.alarmIsActive;
      //   super.initState();
      // }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            title: const Text(
              "View All Operators",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.black, //change your color here
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: giveMeUsers(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Text(
                  "Something went wrong",
                );
              } else {
                Operators = (snapshot.data ?? []) as List;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: Operators.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: const CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3135/3135715.png",
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(Operators[index]),
                      onTap: () {},
                      trailing: Switch(
                        value: alarmIsActiveMap[index] == null
                            ? false
                            : alarmIsActiveMap[index],
                        onChanged: (bool isEnabled) {
                          setState(() {
                            alarmIsActiveMap[index] = isEnabled;
                            Global.shared.alarmIsActive = isEnabled;
                            isEnabled = !isEnabled;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    Future<List<String>> giveMeUsers() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];
    }
    
    class Global {
      static final shared = Global();
      bool alarmIsActive = false;
    }
```

where the output would look like:

[image]

Comment: could you help me to maintain the status of the switch? when I turn the switch off and then press hot reload or navigate to another interface, the switch return to the default value true while it supposes to be false.